# Is Bluetooth 4.2 compatible with 4.0?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I was reading about the compatibility between BT 4.0 and 4.2. I found here and in another forum people saying it's full compatible. Also, according to what I read, the main differences would be basically security, speed and the IoT stuff. So if I run a simple BT connection (no IP) and don't require top speed transmission, can I rely on the fact that 4.0 and 4.2 will be compatible?

My MCU library stack is 4.2 based but I want to make the product 4.0 compatible. Is there anything I should be aware of? Any other functionality/function I should not use?

Comment: It's compatible as long as you don't restrict your application to the use of BLE 4.2 features, such as Secure Connection. In your case it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

4.2 features are negotiated between the Central and the Peripheral. If a 4.2 host tries to negotiate with a 4.0, negotiation will fail because messages are unknown. Error must be assumed as a soft failure meaning feature is not supported for a 4.2 host. For instance:

- length extension in 6.B.5.1.9:

  > If the Link Layer of the master or slave sends the LL_LENGTH_REQ PDU
  >   to a device that does not understand that PDU, then the device should
  >   expect an LL_UNKNOWN_RSP PDU in response. If the Link Layer receives
  >   an LL_UNKNOWN_RSP PDU with the UnknownType field set to LL_LENGTH_REQ,
  >   then it shall not transmit another LL_LENGTH_REQ PDU to the peer
  >   device.
- Secure connection in 3.H.3.5.2:

  > The SC field is a 1-bit flag that is set to one to request LE Secure
  >   Connection pairing, otherwise it shall be set to 0 based on the supported
  >   features of the initiator and responder, the possible resulting pairing
  >   mechanisms are: if both devices support LE Secure Connections, use LE
  >   Secure Connections; otherwise use LE legacy pairing.

So basically, yes, the are fully compatible.

*Side note*: Even in 4.2 spec, all "new" features are optional (length extension, secure connections, etc.). So, as long as the host answers negotiations with messages meaning "I know about them, but I dont support them", it can claim 4.2 compatibility and not actually implement anything fancy ! Most SoC vendors who issued software upgrades to 4.2 for their current hardware actually did that.